# Centralizing Regular Expression Validation Patterns in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I there a way in ASP.Net MVC to have a RegularExpression attribute on a model property to pull the pattern string property from resource file or another class?

When I attempt to use another class I get a message stating that the attribute values must be a constant, typeof expression, or an array.

Ultimately, I'm attempting to abstract some of these patterns so I don't have to update multiple files if a bug is located in a pattern.

### Example:

```
public class MyModel{
    [RegularExpression(StaticPatternClass.EmailPattern, ErrorMessage="invalid email")]
    public string email { get; set;}
}

public static class StaticPatternClass{
    public static string EmailPattern = @"My pattern here";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

public const string EmailPattern ....

instead

Answer (score 2):

The error description is quite clear, it needs to be a constant. A constant value is compiled and cannot be changed. However a regular static string might be changed (more exactly replaced as strings are immutable) during the execution of the program which is not allowed. Try this instead:

```
public static class StaticPatternClass{
    public const string EmailPattern = @"My pattern here";
}
```